# what this regular expression mean '/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/'

Tags: javascript, regex

I could not understand the following code:

```
var req = "google.com/?x=value&y=another";
req = req.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '');
console.log(req);
```

The above code prints **google.com**, its removing the query parameters from the string.

can anyone explain me how the replace function doing this task?

Comment: See yourself, [here](https://regex101.com/r/iT9rU7/1) see in the `EXPLANATION` section on the right top corner

Comment: Just have a look at the explanation of regex101.com: 

https://regex101.com/r/jX2vD8/1

Comment: Which part of it do you find confusing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

/? **matches the character** / **literally**

(?:\?.*)? **Non-capturing group**

\? matches the character **?** literally

.* **matches any character (except newline)**

$ assert position at end of the string